# PHP Library to accept logins from Facebook and Google?

Tags: google, facebook, api, authentication, openid

I'm making a site and I want creating accounts / logging in to be very easy, so I want to support logins with Facebook Connect and Google Accounts. I know both offer APIs, but seems like a lot of coding. Is there a library out there that can handle both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HybridAuth](http://www.phpkode.com/projects/item/hybridauth/) looks like it can do it.